# Prototype.js Test If Element Has Focus

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

So I abandoned prototype.js years and years and years ago for jquery LOL... Now I find myself having to use it again and can't quit figure out how to get this jquery statement out of prototype.js ... can anyone help?

```
if(!$('#search').is(':focus')){
```

Comment: This is how jQuery checks it: `"focus": function(elem) { return elem === document.activeElement && (!document.hasFocus || document.hasFocus()) && !!(elem.type || elem.href || ~elem.tabIndex); },`. Pretty simple.

Comment: Love it thanks!... do you know off hand how that returns? either true/false or what?

Comment: Looks like it returns true/false here is my new script using what you gave me if(document.activeElement && (!document.hasFocus || document.hasFocus()) && !!($('search').type || $('search').href || ~$('search').tabIndex) != true){

Comment: What about `$$('#search:focus')` and then check to see if returns null (or an empty array? my Prototype.js is rusty :-)

Comment: does :focus exist in prototype.js? i didn't even try i guess i just assumed it didnt. I skimmed through the docs and didn't see anything

Comment: looks like my previous if statement using dfsq's solution didn't work im going to try out yours now Pointy

Comment: Awesome Pointy your solution worked best for me! :) 'code'if($$('#search:focus') == ''){'code'

Answer (score 0):

The answer for my question was solved by the comment from Pointy... here is my final solution for anyone else who may need it.

```
if($$('#search:focus') == ''){
```

Comment: try `$$('#search:focus').length == 0`